# Ouath Social Logins in React JS and Node(Express) with different sub domains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have created an app in React and Node(Express) which seems to be working fine on local but I am facing issues on hosting them.

I have option to login using OAuth2(Google, LinkedIn, Twitter, GitHub). I have hosted the client on front.domain.io and server on api.domain.io. When I am clicking on login with google it is redirecting me to an invalid URL. Can someone help me to solve this. Below is my code and the expected URL and current redirection happening.

React Code which redirects to google login page :

```
const googleReqHandler = () => {
    window.open(`${APIURL}/auth/google`, "_self");
  };
```

Node Js Code to handle the redirection and callback

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
  })
);
```

Passport JS config

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `${process.env.APP_URL}/auth/google/callback`,
    },
    async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      const userProfile = profile;
      await usersHelper.createOrUpdate(userProfile);
      done(null, userProfile);
    }
  )
);
```

URLs that I am using in React And Node

```
APIURL : https://api.domain.io

CLIENT_URL : https://front.domain.io
APP_URL : https://api.domain.io
```

The URL that the user is being redirected from when the user clicks **Login with Google** button

```
https://api.domain.io/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.domain.io%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=clientid
```

The URL it should have been redirected to

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/identifier?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.domain.io%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&client_id=clientid&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

I have configured the OAuth in all the developer consoles properly, it is working fine for all the logins on local.
I think that is issue is due to requests generation and the redirection from different subdomains where as on local it is same domain just different port(localhost:3000 and localhost:5000). So can someone help me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably some configuration issues. You may need to debug and check why it's redirecting to a different URL in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

So after not able to find much on the issue, I hosted the backend(node) using heroku and frontend(react) using netlify, after I found the video mentioned below after going through n number of videos and blogs, and everything worked fine. So I had a talk with the devops so got to know that most probably the issue was due to URL rewrites they had used in the IIS on windows server. So we hosted the application on ubuntu using nginx and then everything is working fine. So if any one faces such an issue do check for such URL rewrites if you are hosting it on windows.

Also make sure that the site is hosted on https, as http can give issues when on public domain(Someone had mentioned that in his video). Do add the following lines to your app.js in backend too or else they won't pass session cookies during login process when hosted on public domain with different domains.

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "whatever",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    },
  })
);
```

Here is the link of the video, which helped me to identify this issue and make required changes before hosting such setup as no other video which I referred to showed the hosting process.

[Youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD17CYA1dck&list=LL&index=1)